# What is the preferable date-format used for designing APIs and storage

Tags: api-design, storage, date-format

The date format should support different timezone and Daylight saving issues.

Comment: please add context info: programminglanguage / database-system / type of api / usecase

Comment: See [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339)

Answer (score 8):

[ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It's not just "preferable", it should be the only format you consider.

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"Abstain of ISO8601. It's not just not "preferable", it should be the only format you ignore."_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Comment: @gnat Given that the opposing answer would be heavily down-voted, it would remain clear to future visitors to this question which was the “correct” answer. I answer the question. Additional words would just be waffle.

Comment: as far as I can tell moderators at this site tend to delete answers that appear like voting-based popularity contest, see eg [Top answers duplicated on community wiki question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6213/31260)